# nhibernate queryover how to select an alias column?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Assuming I have three simple tables

```
schedule 
{
    Student student { get; set;}
    Teacher teacher { get; set;}
    bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

Student
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IList<schedule> TeacherMeetings {get; set; }
}
```

and assume teacher has the same thing, name and list of student schedules.

I want to select, from schedule, the list of all student names for a particular teacher. I can write the query for conditions and everything, but having trouble selecting just the student names.

Here is my current query:

```
    DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.Of<Schedule>(() => sAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sAlias.student, () => studentAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sAlias.teacher, () => teacherAlias)
    .Where(() => teacherAlias.MembershipGuid == teacherGuid)
    .AndNot(() => sAlias.isDeleted)
    //.Select(() => studentAlias.Name)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(x => x.student.Name).WithAlias(() => studentAlias.Name))
    .DetachedCriteria
    ;
```

If I comment out all `select`, profiler shows the query being generated as the right one, with right joins on right tables, only, it selects all columns on all tables.

I can't seem to get the `select` right, I only need the `student.Name` only.

How do I write this please? I've been at this for over an hour trying out different things but it is always the select that errors out, saying `NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property` and that studentName isn't recognizable.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a list of strings, you shouldn't need to use `WithAlias`. `WithAlias` is used to project that column into a member on a  result object.

Something like this should work:

```csharp
DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.Of<Schedule>(() => sAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sAlias.student, () => studentAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sAlias.teacher, () => teacherAlias)
    .Where(() => teacherAlias.MembershipGuid == teacherGuid)
    .AndNot(() => sAlias.isDeleted)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => studentAlias.Name))
    .DetachedCriteria;
```

So the following should get you a list of strings:

```cs
IList<string> names = dc.GetExecutableCriteria(session)
    .List<string>();
```

---

**Update** (per comment). Here's how you would order by student name, descending:

```cs
DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.Of<Schedule>(() => sAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sAlias.student, () => studentAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => sAlias.teacher, () => teacherAlias)
    .Where(() => teacherAlias.MembershipGuid == teacherGuid)
    .AndNot(() => sAlias.isDeleted)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => studentAlias.Name))
    .OrderBy(() => studentAlias.Name).Desc()
    .DetachedCriteria;
```

Comment: excellent! that works.. hmm.. so ``withAlias`` is used only with Transform?

Comment: also, how do I order by this ``studentAlias.Name`` now, please?

Comment: @LocustHorde: Yep! `WithAlias` is used with `TransformUsing`. `OrderBy` should be simple enough, one second...